# Cooling induction current generation

Tags: electric-current, power, induction

We know that conducting materials can be heated by electromagnetic induction. Is it possible to generate current using a cooling process?

Comment: No. Why would you think so?

Comment: see while cooling process is heat transfer process, so heat is transfered in metal by lattice vibration or electron transfer. if cooling material kept near coductor will current induce due to magnetic filed created by electron movement.

Comment: Cooling a material does not generate directed electron movement (which would be a current), it just decreases the overall thermic movement. The heating of conductors through which current flows is really just a friction effect and has nothing to do with electromagnetism as such.

Comment: how much % of heat is transfered through electron transfer and is there specific temp. at which it is highest.

Comment: I fail to parse your question. % of what heat? Which electron transfer?

Comment: how much percent of total heat transfer is through electron transfer.

Comment: I fear there may be a language barrier here. There are no electrons "transferred" that I would know of, and which heat transfer (from which system to which system) do you mean? (Perhaps the upvoter can clear up my confusion?)

Comment: Well, 100% of the heat transfer is caused by electron movements. They "bumb" into latice atoms and tranfer there kinetic energy to those atoms. This effect tends to follow Ohms law that derives to $P=R I^2$, where $R$ is a component constant. So the more or the faster electrons (that is, larger current $I$), the larger the power, which is your heat loss every second.

Comment: @user52813 To ask "*Is there a specific temperature of the conductor at which the outwards heat transfer is the highest?*" is another topic. The higher the temperature, the higher the heat transfer to surroundings, since thermal conduction and radiation etc. increases with increasing temperature. This is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: If you heat up the whole material, then **no**.

If you heat up the material in on end (an iron bar e.g.), then **yes**. The [thermoelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect) will cause a small current to flow between the two ends of different temperature.

It looks like you are mistakenly assuming that electromagnetic induction causes heating, which should then be possible to reverse. Well, the heating is more a side effect. It is caused by the resistance in the material. Whenever current flows - regardless of the cause - resistance in the material will cause heating. Electrons making up the current e.g. will bumb into the material atoms and transfer their energy to this material. Which is heat on the macro scale. This heat loss is an irreversible process - you cannot "put the heat back" to regain a current.